# Как переименовать root в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

Как переименовать главного пользователя с сохранением его предыдущих настроек?

Comment: Ну минимум надо затронуть файлы `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group*` и каталог `/root/` переименовать. Вопрос в другом: нафига?

Comment: Компьютер остался от бывшего на нем коллеги, там в итоге пользователь носит его имя и фамилию.

Comment: Можно скриншот где это имя и фамилия высвечивается (само фио можно замазать)

Comment: Например, в случае с публичным глючом в конце файла пишется `имя@имя-System-Product-Name`

Comment: комментарий в публичном ключе можно смело убирать. символы вида `пользователь@машина` в конце публичного ключа — это именно комментарий.

Comment: а что выдаёт `$ id 0` на этой машине?

Comment: `id: 0: такого пользователя нет`

Comment: А что мешает сделать `sudo adduser timur` и жить там?

Comment: Ничего, и это, кстати, вариант, но изначальный вопрос все равно в силе :)

Comment: Я сейчас могу вспомнить знаменитую картинку про троллейбус из буханки хлеба. Но имхо, судя по описанной проблеме - ты работаешь под юзером в котором в n количестве мест прохардкорено имя коллеги и оно прописано НЕ в системе, а в конкретном юзере. Поэтому лучшим решением будет создать свою песочницу, а настройки и документы переносить по мере надобности, потому что `root\sudo` никто не забирал (а если и забирал - сбросить не проблема).

Comment: Создал. Попробовал установить пакет. Но: `merrymaker14 отсутствует в файле sudoers. Данное действие будет занесено в журнал.`.

Comment: `sudo adduser merrymaker14 adm && sudo adduser merrymaker14 sudo`. Делать из под старого профиля конечно же.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo  usermod --login НОВОЕ_ИМЯ СТАРОЕ_ИМЯ
```